# Enhanced For-Loop only uses value from first loop instead of the updated value after a loop has been completed

Tags: java, android, android-room

Edit: Updated my post, the first part with pictures is the update edit.

I use Android Room database. I want to delete Transaction objects. By doing this, the member linked to that transaction will have his balance deducted by the transaction amount. The first loop works well. But every loop that follows after the first loop have this problem: It always uses the getBalance value of the first loop instead of the updated one. I used the debugger to find the problem and I noticed this:

In this example, I delete two transactions, both of them are linked to the same one member.

The transaction ids are changing, but that's correct, because I delete two different transactions.

Both member lists also have a different number. I think that is right, because every transaction has different members in it, so it will get different lists.

But the member number changes (it should be just one member, so shouldn't it use the same number?). That probably, I think, is also the reason why it uses the old getBalance for every loop. I use the @Update method, so why doesn't it use the updated value for, after the first one, following loops?

[image]
[image]

This code works like this:
I have many transactions. This code loops for every transaction. Let's say I have two transactions, first one having deletebalance = 10 and second one deletebalance = 5. I have two members, first one having helper = 30 and helper = 10.

Normally, after the loops end, I should have for the first member the balance = 15 and for the second member the balance = -5.

The first transaction starts the loop. It works normally and I have the balances for first member = 20 and for the second member = 0.

The second transaction starts the loop. This is where the problem is: Instead of using 20 and 0 for helper, it uses the old values 30 and 10 for helper. It doesn't use the value I set in the setbalance method in my loop.

I could have as many transactions I want, it always uses the helper from the first loop. How can I do so that the loop uses the updated value when the next transaction starts the loop?

I get the transactionids passed by the adapter.

```
for (String transactionid : transactionArray){
    Transaction transaction = mTransactionViewModel.getTransaction(Long.parseLong(transactionid));
    final BigDecimal deletebalance = transaction.getBalance();

    List<Member> members = mTransactionViewModel.getMembersFromTransactionList(Long.parseLong(transactionid));

    for (Member member : members) {
        if (member != null) {
        BigDecimal helper = member.getBalance();
        BigDecimal helpbalance = helper.subtract(deletebalance);
        member.setBalance(helpbalance);
        mMemberViewModel.update(member);
        }
    }
}
```

Member Entity:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "MemberID")
private long id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "FirstName")
private String firstname;

@ColumnInfo(name = "Surname")
private String surname;

@ColumnInfo(name = "MemberBalance")
private BigDecimal balance;

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public BigDecimal getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}


public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Member(String firstname, String surname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.balance = new BigDecimal(0).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
}
```

This is what I try to achieve: I delete multiple transactions and I want to subtract all the transactions values from every member. Every transaction goes through this loop, first transaction deletes and subtracts its value from all members, then the second one deletes and subtracts its value from all members, etc.

For example: We only look at one member.

```
BigDecimal helper = member.getBalance();
```

Here, helper is 30.

```
BigDecimal helpbalance = helper.subtract(deletebalance);
```

helper (30) - deletebalance (10) = 20

```
member.setBalance(helpbalance);
```

member.setBalance(20);

```
mMemberViewModel.update(member);
```

The inner loop ends. The outer loop starts the next loop with the next transaction.

But what happens in the next loop? this: It's the same member like in the first loop, but with the next transaction. Here the member should have the updated value. The getBalance should give the value 20. Then the second transaction value gets deducted from the 20. This is what actually happens:

```
BigDecimal helper = member.getBalance();
```

Here, helper is 30, but it should be 20 because the first loop sets value to 20 with setBalance.

```
BigDecimal helpbalance = helper.subtract(deletebalance);
```

helper (30) - deletebalance (10) = 20
It should be like this: helper (20) - deletebalance (5) = 15

```
member.setBalance(helpbalance);
```

member.setBalance(15);

```
mMemberViewModel.update(member);
```

Comment: *"It doesn't use the value I set in the setbalance method in my loop."* I'm confused. The `setBalance` call in the first loop is on the first member in `members`; in the second loop, dealing with the *second* member in `members`, why would you expect that second member to reflect the balance set on the first member? They're different objects (presumably)...?

Comment: Both members have different balances, in my example they have 30 and 10, but when the second transaction starts instead (for first member) of using 20 as value, it still uses 30 and instead (for second member) of using 0 as value it uses 10.

Comment: You should post what you're trying to achieve. For example, "I want to check every member's transactions and subtract a specific amount from each of them".

Comment: I delete multiple transactions and I want to subtract all the transactions values from every member. Every transaction goes through this loop, first transaction deletes and subtracts its value from all members, then the second one deletes and subtracts its value from all members, etc.

Comment: You should show also the Member cass code.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make out what you're trying to describe at all. Unless there's cross-talk between the members, what happens in the first loop iteration will have nothing whatsoever to do with the second loop iteration. It sounds like there's cross-talk, or stale information in the members, or similar, but there isn't enough above for us to really be able to help I'm afraid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder does this maybe help? I updated my code a little bit.

Comment: I think the problem is here `List<Member> members = mTransactionViewModel.getMembersFromTransactionList(Long.parseLong(transactionid));` This is returning new list every time

Comment: This code should be run in a transactional context, are you doing it?

Comment: Put that line outside the outer for loop and it'll work

Comment: @NiVeR it works in a AsyncTask. The insert and update method also work with AsyncTask and they work.

Comment: @rafid059 I can't, otherwise the loop won't work because it's missing transactionid.

Comment: *"But what happens on the next loop?"* Please be specific: The inner loop (on members), or the outer loop (on transactions)?

Comment: `mMemberViewModel.update(member);` does this update the value in the db?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is this more clear?

Comment: @rafid059 after the update method, I put a log: The log returns member.getBalance() and it returns the correct value. But when the outer loop starts the next loop, the inner loops helper = member.getBalance() doesn't get updated.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I updated my post, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by just deleting one at a time. That works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loop, for testing, reload the member entity by its id.

```
Member currentMember = entityManager.get(member.id)
```

If that has the correct value, your entity is storing and the problem is that mMemberViewModel.update(member)/getMembersFromTransactionList are using state entities.  If that case we will have to see that code as well.

If that value is wrong, you are not committing your transaction between outer loops.

---

Are you sure you are getting the same members back when you call:

```
List<Member> members = mTransactionViewModel.getMembersFromTransactionList(Long.parseLong(transactionid));
```

Log your member objects and make sure the second time around they have the same ID.

If they are the same IDs, did you commit your transaction?

ARE YOU USING THE OLD TRANSACTION_ID TO GET THE MEMBERS?

To check if your database is persisting, try something like this.

```js
List<Member> members = mTransactionViewModel.getMembersFromTransactionList(Long.parseLong(transactionid));

for (Member member : members) {
    member.setBalance(new BigDecimal(12));
}

for (Member member : members) {
    if (member.getBalance().intValue() != 12){
      // bad
    }
}

for (Member member : members) {
    mMemberViewModel.update(member);
}

for (Member member : members) {
    if (member.getBalance().intValue() != 12){
      // bad
    }
}

transactionId = NEW_TRANSACTION_ID
mTransactionViewModel.getMembersFromTransactionList(Long.parseLong(transactionid));

for (Member member : members) {
    if (member.getBalance().intValue() != 12){
      // bad
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you use are using an attached entity by using the result value from merge(...) in your provider.

Comment: They do have the same ID. I made my example a bit more clear.

Comment: Did you commit your transaction?

Comment: Yes, I did commit the transactions.

Comment: Do you need a new transaction id to get the changes?

Comment: The outer loop always uses new transaction id. That's good, that shows that the outer loop proceeds to next transaction. This is what I found out: After the update method, I put a log: The log returns member.getBalance() and it returns the correct value. But when the outer loop starts the next loop, the inner loops helper = member.getBalance() doesn't get updated and it still uses the old value.

Comment: Perhaps List<Member> members is getting mutated and you could make a copy using 

members = new ArrayList(members)

Comment: instead of update(...), do you have method like merge(...) that returns a new entity?

Comment: No, I don't. There's nothing that could possible return a new entity. And the idea with ArrayList also doesn't work.

Comment: If your entity is detached, and your call to getMembersFromTransactionList returns attached ones, you are going to have a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176737/discussion-between-lordgash-and-steven-spungin).

Comment: OK, but I think the loop is not the problem, its seems to be JPE related.

Comment: If I delete on transaction at a time, it works. With multiple, in the next outer loop, it always uses the old value from the first inner loop for helper.

Comment: Please try to call merge instead of update, set a breakpoint, and compare the entity returned to the entity sent in.  I think you are dealing with 2 different objects.

Comment: Okay, I‘ll try that later. But at the end of the inner loop, it sets the correct value, then at begin of the next outer loops, the inner loop alwaya uses the same getBalance value like in the first outer loop...

Comment: Are you calling update on a detached entity?  Where do you commit the transaction?

Comment: If I delete only one transaction, then everything works fine, the new setBalance gets saved, so I don‘t think I call update on a detached entity. But if I delete multiple ones, the getBalance uses the old value. I have a main activity, where I insert a transaction and that works fine. Only the getBalance is making a problem.

Comment: Maybe your database is auto-commiting the first transaction (delete) and you have to disable that feature, or start a new transaction for every op?

Comment: I get the transaction ids and I make a new object with the corresponding id for every loop. Isn't that making a new transaction for every loop?

Comment: I will update my solution with a test to show that other commits may be happening.

Comment: Could we continue this discussion in the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176888/discussion-between-lordgash-and-steven-spungin).

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation that I can see is that the changes that you perform are not peristed in the database. Try to control whether you are in a context of a transaction and when does it end. Since you are repeating the query for each transaction you are expecting that the changes from the previous transactions are already persisted in the database, check this.

Comment: After the update method, I put a log: The log returns member.getBalance() and it returns the correct value. But when the outer loop starts the next loop, the inner loops helper = member.getBalance() doesn't get updated and it still uses the old value.

Comment: Do you commit a transaction? What is the content of `mMemberViewModel.update(Member)`?

Comment: The setBalance method sets the new value. The 'mMemberViewModel.update(member)' updates the member. This method is in my DAO: @Update void update(Member... member)